# ignite addressresolver with internal switch?

Tags: java, ignite

I'm unable to connect to an Ignite cluster server (192.168.10.226) that is behind a ASUS switch from a computer (192.168.10.2) that is on the other side of the switch. Both sides of the switch share the same network 192.168.10.x. I found out that the switch replaces addresses with its own address. On the server I see this log:

```
[06:00:27,611][INFO][tcp-disco-sock-reader-#9%Test Cluster%][TcpDiscoverySpi] Started serving remote node connection [rmtAddr=/192.168.10.1:33493, rmtPort=33493]
```

It then tries for very long to connect to the cluster but it shows timeout messages and eventually even makes the server node disconnect.

Although my computer has IP address 192.168.10.2 it looks like 192.168.10.1 is what the switch forwards to the server. Is this legal NAT?

Is there a way to workaround this maybe with the BasicAddressResolver?

As a note: I'm able to ssh into the server from my computer. However, also  there netstat shows:

```
Active Internet connections (w/o servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 192.168.10.226:22       192.168.10.1:11060      ESTABLISHED
```

Any idea or help? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I properly understand you, when node trying to resolve local addresses, it resolves 192.168.10.1 instead of 192.168.10.226 and then send it to the cluster for other nodes.

In this case, it's not necessary to use BasicAddressResolver, you can just set **IgniteConfiguration.setLocalHost** and Ignite will use only this address for this node, instead of resolving all addresses for all network interfaces.

Comment: No, it's not the node that resolves its local address as 192.168.10.1 but the network switch between the node and the server does this by applying NAT. I've tried setLocalHost to the correct IP address (192.168.10.2) of the node but still the switch applies NAT and replaces it with .1. Can this NAT situation be resolved with the BasicAddressResolver?